# Can't get into ValueEventListener while trying to get data using GeoFire in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to call already saved data using `GeoFire`, but not trying to get a single object .. am trying to loop through many items. here is the code am using:

```java
    public void gettingStationData() {
        Log.e("where are we now", "getting station data function");
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("station");
        mDatabaseReference.child("bus").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.e("where are we now", "started on datachange");
                DatabaseError databaseError = null;
                Log.d("the error ", databaseError.getMessage());
                for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("where are we now", "started the loop");
                    String theName = String.valueOf(child.getValue());
                    Double theLat = (Double) child.child(theName).child("l").child("0").getValue();
                    Double theLong = (Double) child.child(theName).child("l").child("1").getValue();
                    LatLng newBusStationLocation = new LatLng(theLat, theLong);
                    setStationMarker(newBusStationLocation, theName);
                    Log.e("fetched data", String.valueOf(newBusStationLocation));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

as you see I've used `Log` methods to debug the process. 
both `Log.e("where are we now", "getting station data function");` and `Log.e("where are we now", "started on datachange");` are shown, but once I get into the loop. nothing appears which means the loop is not even being started.

And here is how my database looks like :

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767 maybe have a look at this

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you have any message in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added it like this `                DatabaseError databaseError = null;
                Log.d("the error ", databaseError.getMessage());
` and i got this error message `    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.getMessage()' on a null object reference
`

Comment: Add that code to your question.

Comment: Code updated, added this 2 lines to the question